# How to remove wrong spacing after section?

Tags: tables, sectioning, vertical-alignment, tabu

I'm trying to create multiple tables with the same width, alignment and spacing. 
All tables looks fine, except for the first one after the section...

```
\section*{Section}
\begin{tabu}to \textwidth {|p{3cm}|X|}
  \hline
  tabu1 & test \\ \hline
  test & test \\ \hline
\end{tabu}
\vspace{1em}
\begin{tabu}to \textwidth {|p{3cm}|X|}
  \hline
  tabu2 & test \\ \hline
  test & test \\ \hline
\end{tabu}
\vspace{1em}
\begin{tabu}to \textwidth {|p{3cm}|X|}
  \hline
  tabu3 & test \\ \hline
  test & test \\ \hline
\end{tabu}
\vspace{1em}
\begin{tabu}to \textwidth {|p{3cm}|X|}
  \hline
  tabu4 & test \\ \hline
  test & test \\ \hline
\end{tabu}
```

[image]

How to add the vspace to the first table and why is it like it is?

Comment: Welcome. Could you provide a full minimal working example with \documentclass and \end{document}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have entered it, the `\vspace`'s don't come into effect until there is a linebreak in the output (and then they accumulate).  Cf.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

text\vspace{1em}text\vspace{1em}text\vspace{1em}
text\vspace{1em}text\vspace{1em}text\vspace{1em}
text\vspace{1em}text\vspace{1em}text\vspace{1em}
text\vspace{1em}text\vspace{1em}text\vspace{1em}
text\vspace{1em}text\vspace{1em}text\vspace{1em}
text\vspace{1em}text\vspace{1em}text\vspace{1em}
text\vspace{1em}text\vspace{1em}text\vspace{1em}
text\vspace{1em}text\vspace{1em}text\vspace{1em}
text\vspace{1em}text\vspace{1em}text\vspace{1em}

\end{document}
```

Instead you need to end the paragraph before adding the `\vspace`.  You will discover you need to cancel the paragraph indent too with a `\noindent`:

[image: Sample two]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}

\section*{Section}

\begin{tabu}to \textwidth {|p{3cm}|X|}
  \hline
  tabu1 & test \\ \hline
  test & test \\ \hline
\end{tabu}

\vspace{1em}\noindent
\begin{tabu}to \textwidth {|p{3cm}|X|}
  \hline
  tabu2 & test \\ \hline
  test & test \\ \hline
\end{tabu}

\vspace{1em}\noindent
\begin{tabu}to \textwidth {|p{3cm}|X|}
  \hline
  tabu3 & test \\ \hline
  test & test \\ \hline
\end{tabu}

\noindent
\begin{tabu}to \textwidth {|p{3cm}|X|}
  \hline
  tabu4 & test \\ \hline
  test & test \\ \hline
\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```